# Alfresco optimal folder structure

Tags: lucene, alfresco, directory-structure

I need to create a tree of folders and documents on Alfresco (4.2 Enterprise Edition and SOLR for the indexes). My tree will have more than 2 million documents. My idea is to create a main folder, "MY_REPO", inside the "User Homes" space. "MY_REPO" will have 5000 subfolders (each one by a user that uses my application). Each user can organize the subfolders inside with java backed webscripts which create nodes and upload documents.

My application has two parts: One that allows navigatation inside these folders, to see documents and custom properties of each node, and search with lucene or FTS inside all the tree. And another part to upload documents and create new folders.

I have a basic, but important, question. Is having these 5000 folders in "MY_REPO" a bad idea? would it be better to create more structure of folders (for example, divide this 5000 in groups of 100)? Is there are a limit, or recommended limit, on folders inside another folder? How do you organize your structure on Alfresco to have good navigation, and search documents efficiently? Creating a good structure is basic, and I can't find information about this, or recommendations about the number of levels and folders.

Also, is Folder and Space the same? Is it typical, when working with a lot of data, to create one workspace (SpaceStore) and put the data inside the "User Homes" directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not recommended** to have 5000 subfolders under one root folder.It will impact your performance very badley.
You need to divide repository based on some logic structure in such a way that you could minimize the number of subfolders at each level.

Logical group based on some criteria which make sense for your solution.

> is Folder and Space the same?

YES (Space is the name given to contents which appears as a folder inside alfresco.Reason is they are smart folders with many advance capablities which normal folder does not have.)
 Is it typical, when working with a lot of data, to create one workspace (SpaceStore) and put the data inside the "User Homes" directory?

> Is it typical, when working with a lot of data, to create one
>   workspace (SpaceStore) and put the data inside the "User Homes"
>   directory

No, You should always create folder strcture based on some criteria which will distribute contents evenly across the repository. For Instance, based on time stemps, based on groups of users etc...

Edit:
Subfolders number should never cross 1000. Lesser the number of sub folder better the performance and ease of navigation. "User Homes" normally contains User specific spaces and contents which are specific to that user should go there. You could create Folder tree under Main repository Folder.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you clarify a few things about this questions?

Comment: What number of subfolders, more or less, are recommended? I can think about a different folder structure, for example, divide the folders on months or years, but I need to know some type of recommendation about sizing. Not exceed X subfolders never, for example, and what number is X more or less.

Comment: And moreover, all this folder structure may be in "User Homes" space? When I ask about put the data inside "User Homes" I meant put not directly, I meant with a folder tree with subfolders with a "User Homes" like the main father. I did not explain well. "User Homes" is always the father of the structure?

Comment: Thanks! I will follow your recommendations. Are there some place where I could found recommendations like the 1000 folders limit? Maybe a link with other recommendations like this.